# Is the ARRL website distributing malware? I'm not sure who to contact

Tags: arrl

When I was visiting the ARRL/become a VE site on my iPhone and I try to download the PDF for the application form, it redirects me to a malware site. I have confirmed this with other ham friends and we are sure our phones don't have any locally installed malware. Some times it won't redirect you, but if you keep trying to click on the pdf link, it will redirect.

http://www.arrl.org/become-an-arrl-ve

The link is  ARRL VE pdf application at the bottom of the page.  ONLY CLICK ON THE PDF LINK IF YOU KNOW WHAT YOU'RE DOING

Who do I contact in ARRL regarding this issue?

EDIT: this can be reproduced by visting the link on an iPhone

EDIT 2: I have sent an email to ARRL. I will post an answer with their response

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112294/discussion-on-question-by-r-sun-is-the-arrl-website-distributing-malware-im-no).

Answer (score 1):

I visited the page and clicked on all application links and had no issue getting to the PDF page as one might expect. For reference, I am running Firefox v79 on a Windows 10 PC. I am not sure where the problem is stemming from, but if you haven't already I would see if you or any of your ham friends could reproduce on a PC. If the problem is still present, I would suggest using the contact info on the page (vec@arrl.org) as they would either be able to check the page or would be in close contact with someone who can.

Comment: Hello and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have maybe got some antivirus software installed on your computer that is being overly sensitive with links to PDF files served from HTTP sites (rather than HTTPS).

My Mac opened the PDF just fine without complaints.

I don't think there is any actual malware on there, but it might be tripping your antivirus or malware-detection software as a false positive.

Comment: This happened on an iPhone. Doesnt seem to work with computers

Comment: Scott, should we migrate this question? See comments on OQ.

Answer (score 1):

https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/results/Arrl.org didn't find any malware.

However, one of the things it reports is:

> Our automated scan detects outdated software on your site. Missing security updates can leave your site vulnerable.

However, their outdated Apache webserver is considered low risk.

---

Clicking on https://www.arrl.org/news/search/Tag.name:digital%20mode just now redirected me to a gambling website. Seems they DO have some issues!

This was on an Android tablet in Chrome. It even circumvented the 'no malware' [Cloudflare DNS IPs](https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-1-1-1-1-for-families/) and [PfblockerNG](https://protectli.com/kb/how-to-setup-pfblockerng/) in my [pfSense](https://www.pfsense.org/) router.